# Spring Security Authentication is null after Error page redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, error-handling

**Some background**

While I was trying to build a navbar with user's information and roles access I faced some problems to retrieve those informations on a 404 error page from the Authentication ( Spring Security ) on a handler interceptor.

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticationHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private IAuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if (modelAndView != null) {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication(); // <- Unexpected Null
            if (authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            modelAndView.getModel().put("user",
                new UserModel(
                    authentication.getName(), 
                    AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities())
                        )
                    ); //put

            } //fi

        }//fi

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {}

}
```

IAuthenticationFacade was implemented as suggested at [baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security).

**The problem**

After I authenticate with some user, all pages requests will go thru *postHandle* and it's possible to get the current user data. Except when the page is redirected due to some 404.

The following line is returning null.

```
Authentication authentication = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication();
```

**Error redirect**

```java
@Configuration
public class ServerPropertiesConfig extends ServerProperties {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        super.customize(container);
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/errors/404/"));
    }
}
```

When I access some page like *localhost/non-existing-page/* it will be redirected to *localhost/errors/404/* and handled at the following controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/errors")
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{error}/")
    public String errorRedirect(@PathVariable String error) {
        return "errors/error" + error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation if you want to get authetined customer.

Comment: Where exactly do you mean? On ErrorController, ServerPropertiesConfig  or AuthenticationHandlerInterceptor ?